# Registry Expiry Date

Tags: domains, whois, expiry

I'm fairly new to dealing with domain names and I have a question that's been puzzling me. Upon checking the WHOIS information for my domain, I came across two distinct expiration dates:

> Registry Expiry Date: 2023-06-25
> Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2023-10-31

I'm finding it hard to determine when my domain will actually expire and subsequently go offline. Is it on the earlier date of 2023-06-25, or will it be later on 2023-10-31? My concern has grown because the first date is just around the corner, and, unfortunately, I won't be able to reach out to my hosting provider over the weekend. I only became aware of this today, so I realize I'm cutting it very close, but I'd really appreciate some clarity on this matter.

Comment: What is the TLD of this domain? Are you seeing these two dates in the same whois lookup? I would expect either one or the other (depending on the WHOIS server), and they _should_ be the "same" in my experience? Since the first date has now past what have you found out?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking in https://lookup.icann.org/en/lookup, the official ICANN lookup site?

If I look there it only has the `Registry expiry date` which is what I would trust.

[image]